# Secure communication on Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, chat, encryption

I am looking for an app (or other method) to securely message my friends on other mobile devices.

Specifically:

- use on different operating systems (Android and iOS)
- group conversations
- encryption (eg. end-to-end encryption)
- protection against MITM attacks
- open source (so that it can be audited by anyone)

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with "securely"?

Comment: @unor: End-to-end encryption, and the likes ...

Answer (score 2):

You can try ChatSecure - https://chatsecure.org/. It offers end to end encryption via OTR. It is open source and available both on iOS and Android. Group chat encryption is dependent if your XMPP server provider offers or enforces encrypted connection to it's clients, most XMPP servers support it. If you are unsure, you can test a server at [xmpp.net](http://xmpp.net).

Comment: Does it support "group conversations"?

Comment: I tried ChatSecure and the group chat didn't seem to be encrypted, only the 1-on-1 chats.

Answer (score 2):

I recently switched from Whatsapp to [Telegram](https://telegram.org), mainly because it has self destructing messages, but the features you want, and extra are also here:

- Android and iOS and Windows Phone and OSX and Linux
- End-to-end encryption<sup>**1**</sup>
- Group chats ([up to 200 people](https://telegram.org/faq#q-what-is-telegram-what-do-i-do-here))
- Free, no subscriptions, no ads
- Uses phone numbers (like Whatsapp)
- Over the internet
- Use on multiple devices (unlike Whatsapp)
- Send self-destructing messages (in secret chats, see below)
- Mostly open source

<sup>**1**</sup>End-to-end encryption:

In Telegram, there are 2 types of chats - normal chat, and secret chat.

**Normal chat**: data is in the cloud, encrypted

**Secret chat**: data does not stay in the cloud once delivered; end-to-end encryption; [Diffie-Helman Key Exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange)

If you want to know more about the technical details, see the [FAQ for the Technically Inclined](https://core.telegram.org/techfaq), or just the [regular FAQ](https://telegram.org/faq).

Comment: Don't rely on "self-destructing messages", anyone can take a screenshot or even a picture of the phone with a camera

Comment: After reading [this](http://unhandledexpression.com/2013/12/17/telegram-stand-back-we-know-maths/) I'm not so sure it's that secure.

Comment: @user2813274 True, but that was just a plus point.

Comment: @gartenriese it's your choice in the end, if you wanted protection from the government, you should have said so in the question. This is a very secure messaging app if you use the secret chat, with E-E encryption, as you said in your comment you wanted.

Comment: @ṧнʊß: "This is a very secure messaging app", has there been an official audit of some kind? Who is saying that it's very secure beside the devs? Sorry, I don't mean to be rude, I'm just skeptical.

Comment: @gartenriese You're right, there hasn't been an *official* audit, although they do give a reward for people who do find flaws in their security, but it's unknown how many people actually tried to do so. If you don't trust them, or their secret chats, don't use it, it's just an option for you to consider :)

Comment: here is a comparison: https://www.eff.org/secure-messaging-scorecard, Telegram lacks some security features